# Offline and Portable PHP text editor that have Live Preview functionality

Tags: php, text-editor, offline, ide, portable

Is there a text editor or IDE for PHP (and if possible, include HTML and CSS) that is:

- Offline (do not need internet in order to function)
- Portable (extract from a zip file and run immediately)
- Live Preview (make changes to php and I will instantly see those changes on screen)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in order to view your PHP, you will need a PHP interpreter (php.exe) **and** a server on which to run a browser to display your PHP.

Probably the most popular Widows (you didn't specify, so I am guessing) [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) setups is [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbportable/): You can download the portable version from [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp), or use another of your choice.

After that, use the portable version of your favourite PHP IDE, or search for something else.

The most popular/powerful is [PHPstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and there is a portable version of the Community Edition [here](https://github.com/tvollstaedt/PhpStormPortable).

Before using that, I used CodeLobster for PHP for years. The free protable edition can be downloaded from [here](http://www.codelobster.com/download.html).

I also used NetBeans for years, for many languages, including PPH. The free portable edition is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbportable/).